Django - Custom Error Templates not rendering
I have some custom templates in my django app. But these are not being rendered and instead displays the basic template:
500 Internal Server Error
Exception inside application.

Daphne

Edit: If I move my dev.py (used on local to DEBUG = False), then the template is rendered.
This is my setup:
Views.py (app level: main):
def custom_500(request):
    return render(request,'main/500.html', status=500)

templates (app level: main with path: templates->main->500html)
500.html custom template file

urls.py (project level)
from main.views import custom_400, custom_500
from django.conf.urls import handler500, handler400
handler500 = 'main.views.custom_500'

settings (folder)
staging.py:
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domainname.com' ]
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True

I also have a base.py in my setting folder, but cannot see anything I should report on there.
I tried to list all the checks I have tried:
In heroku app shell:
print(settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS) # returned the domain name
print(settings.DEBUG) # returned false
print(os.getenv('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE')) # mysite.settings.staging
print(settings.CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE) # true (just in case I would the app would be treated as non prod)
print(settings.SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT) # true (just in case I would the app would be treated as non prod)

and finally:
>>> from django.shortcuts import render 
>>> from django.test import RequestFactory
>>> request = RequestFactory().get('/')
>>> render(request,'main/500.html', status=500)

#returned: <HttpResponse status_code=500, "text/html; charset=utf-8">

I am running out of idea, and I am sure its probably something simple.
I am hoping someone may have some suggestion.

in debug, some custom error handler not work. because they are use default handler.

@django.seolpyo.com is there a way to override this? I am surprise this is not something Django could support.

just set DEBUG=False, and check handler.

@django.seolpyo.com DEBUG=False is already set to false. It seems the handler gets called, but the template is not being displayed. if I set DEBUG=False on local, the template is being displayed. (Not sure I understood your point)

are you sure handelr template path is correct {template dir}/main/500.html? and add screenshot.

@django.seolpyo.com sorry I didnt see you replied. I "figured" out the source my problem, but not an actual solution. I have been using Daphne as a server, somehow moving back to Gunicorn has solved the rendering problem.

There are probably several ways to land this, but below is what I do. While there could be some optimization to this, it works well so long as the error is within the django app and not with the webserver itself.
in urls.py: (don't see any difference here).
if not DEBUG:  # i don't want custom error handling in my dev environment because i want to see the dump to help with troubleshooting.
    handler500 = '<project>.views.custom_500'

in views.py: I see some differences here... don't know if they are necessarily material or not.
def custom_500(request, *args, **argv):
    context = {'<load up the data i need to send to the custom template>',}
    t = loader.get_template('error.html')
    response = HttpResponseServerError(t.render(context))
    response.status_code = 500   # need to set this to ensure flags the error and sends dump data to admins.
    return response


Hi there! I will test that over the weekend, I will let you know!

hello there. The solution didnt work, but since you took the time to reply I thought I would give you some update. I solved my problem by moving back to Gunicorn (I was using Daphne). I dont know if Daphne is really necessary for what I am running and idally I would like to avoid touching this part of Django, as I really struggle to understand it. I might create a seperate post to see if any one would have an answer.

fair and TYVM for the update. I do run Gunicorn and maybe that's why it works for me :) Cheers!
